# Is it possible to compile NDesk.DBus and NDesk.DBus.GLib for windows?

Tags: c#, mono, dbus

I used cygwin to compile it and I get the following error.

```
{"Unable to load DLL 'libc': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
```

when the following method is called.

```
[DllImport ("libc", SetLastError=true)]
protected static extern int socket (int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

My google seaches haven't turned up anything useful. Are there any other windows dbus clients/bindings for c#?

Answer (score 0):

try to include file in your project and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

Comment: MSVCRT seems to be libc analogue for windows.

Comment: according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2.aspx it doesn't contain a socket function.

Answer (score 0):

DBus is a Linux technology and looking at the NDesk.Dbus code I can see its using exclusively unix functionality and no Windows implementation of that either. Additionally as far as I can tell the C# implementation has not been updated for the past 2 years (doesn't mean it's not complete though) and as far as I can tell the glib wrapper to dbus is also unix only.

If you were so keen on using Dbus on windows I guess you will have to compile it yourself - http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus#Windows_port and also compile the glib dbus bindnings and then ndesk.dbus.glib.

Edit: Also check this bug report which has a few pointers to windows builds and libs for dbus: http://code.google.com/p/inkboardng/issues/detail?id=5

Comment: I have dbus running on my windows computer under cygwin. I'm just having trouble with the c# bindings.